# Android Error on ListView with a section seperator?

Tags: java, android, listview

[this is the target listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZcNA.png) in the android app I want.

As you can see,  there are 2 types of cells, "orange" and "red" and I can put it quite easily in a ListView as a ListView can have different types of cells. I am wondering for the seperator middle part, of which there will only be 1 in the listview, how should I approach it? Should it also just be another type of cell or is there a better way to do something like this?

Comment: it's easy , each list view item has its specific layout and you can change color depend on the item, so you can also change the item for example to gray for divider and invisible other elements .

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved by using **"RecyclerView"** and **"RecyclerView.Adapter"**.

In the adpater class, *Override getItemViewType method* and specify the condition based on the position, what type of view you want.

After that, in **"onCreateViewHolder method"**, create a ViewHolder instance based on the itemViewType returned above.

After that, in **"onBindViewHolder method"** cast the received holder into respective viewholder depending upon the itemViewType.

**PS : The ViewHolders created below can contain either listview (Recycler/ListView) or simple views(TextView etc.)**

***Example :***

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          switch(viewType){
              case R.layout.list_item_one : 
                      return ViewHolderOne(LayoutInflator.from(parent.context()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_one, parent, false));          
              case R.layout.list_item_two : 
                      return ViewHolderTwo(LayoutInflator.from(parent.context()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_two, parent, false));          
              default : 
                      return ViewHolderDefault(LayoutInflator.from(parent.context()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_default, parent, false));
          }

    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
       int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
       swtich(viewType){
             case R.layout.list_item_one : 
                   ViewHolderOne holder = (ViewHolderOne) viewHolder; //perform your operations here... 
             break;
             
             case R.layout.list_item_two : 
                   ViewHolderTwo holder = (ViewHolderTwo) viewHolder; //perform your operations here... 
             break; 
             
             default : 
                   ViewHolderDefault holder = (ViewHolderDefault) viewHolder; //perform your operations here... 
             break;
       }
 
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return //getListSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 1: return R.layout.list_item_one;
            case 2: return R.layout.list_item_two;
            default: return R.layout.list_item_default;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is R.layout.list_item_default? Is it the "separator"?

Comment: No, it's specifically not a separator. It could be any view/viewgroup/listview you want it to be or you can even omit it according to your usecase. In the example given by you, it could be the another list after the separator.

Comment: This doesnt work if I have multiple cells. Ie, in your `getItemViewType` you are taking in the position. What if for positions `1, 2, 3` I have `list_item_one` and `4` is the seperator and `5, 6, 7` is the `list_item_two`? How would that work?